# Why $\liminf_{t\to \infty }f(t)\neq \liminf_{n\to \infty }f(t_n)$ where $t_n\to \infty $?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.

Q1) I know that for example $$\lim_{t\to \infty }f(t)=\ell$$
if and only if for all sequence $(x_n)$ s.t. $x_n\to \infty $ we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty }f(x_n)=\ell.$$

I had an exam, and I took a sequence $t_n\to \infty $ and wrote $$\liminf_{t\to \infty }f(t)=\lim_{n\to \infty }f(t_n),$$
but the teacher assistant says that it's wrong, but I don't understand why.

Q2) Also, if $f$ is continuous, then I know that $$\liminf_{t\to \infty }f(t)=\liminf_{\substack{t\to \infty \\ t\in\mathbb Q}}f(t),$$
so if I take an enumeration $\{t_n\}$ of $\mathbb Q$ s.t. $t_n\to \infty $, don't we have $$\liminf_{t\to \infty }f(t)=\lim_{n\to \infty }f(t_n)\ \ ?$$

Comment: For questions about what the teacher assistant said, ask the teacher assistant.  He/she knows other details that we do not, which may be relevant.

Answer (score 6):

**1.** Take $$f(t)=\begin{cases}1&t\in \mathbb N\\ 0&\text{othewise}\end{cases}.$$

If $t_n=n$, then $$\liminf_{t\to \infty }f(t)=0<1=\liminf_{n\to \infty }f(t_n).$$

**2.** Such enumeration doesn't exist. Indeed, if such enumeration exist, then all subsequence would converges to $\infty $, what contradict density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I would like to add that we only have $\limsup t_n = \infty$, where $(t_n)$ is an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$, instead of $\lim$

Answer (score 0):

Let consider for example

$$f(t)=\sin (2\pi x) \implies \liminf_{t\to \infty }f(t)=-1<0=\liminf_{n\to \infty }f(t_n)$$